# QT 5.8.0 building on Mingw-w64

Tags: build, mingw-w64, qt5.8

I am building `QT 5.8.0` source using [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). I follow steps described [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW) under section
"Build Qt with MinGW for a x64 (x86_64) target".

Downloaded QT 5.8.0 source from http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.zip and extracted to folder E:\QTMinGW64\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0

Downloaded MinGW-w64-install.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/latest/download and installed it under E:\QTMinGW64\mingw-w64-v6.3.0\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1

I also install perl, jom and fart under E:\QTMinGW64\mingw-w64-v6.3.0\tools

I created a build directory E:\QTMinGW64\qt-5.8.0-x64-build.

1. Invoked cmd.exe
2. Execute the following:

`set PATH=E:\QTMinGW64\mingw-w64-v6.3.0\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-    rev1\mingw64\bin;E:\QTMinGW64\tools\perl\bin;E:\QTMinGW64\tools\jom;E:\QTMinGW64\tools\fart;C:\Windows\System32;`

`set LANG=en`

`cd E:\IMRI\QTMinGW64\qt-5.8.0-x64-build`

3. Run configure command under qt source
   `> E:\QTMinGW64\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\configure -platform win32-g++ -opensource -debug -debug-and-release  -confirm-license -static -opengl desktop -openssl -plugin-sql-odbc -plugin-sql-sqlite -nomake examples -nomake tests`

The `configure` execution proceeds for a while and then stops with `checking for gold linker` and a windows pop-up appears showing error `ld.gold.exe has stopped working`.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

What I tried so far:

1. Run cmd.exe as administrator
2. Stopped anti-virus software

Comment: Hey, were you ever able to solve the issue? I'm trying to compile QT for minGWx64 too

Comment: No. I switched to Visual studio compiler.